# C++ compile time interpretation of sub-vectors and members

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo, rvalue

I have a particle class which keeps the position, velocity and the acceleration of an object. I can access the related part of the vector via `.position()`, `.velocity()` and `.acceleration()`. I also can access each single number like `.velocity_x()`, `.velocity_y()`, `.velocity_z()` etc. what I would like to do is to access the z part of velocity this way:

```
p.velocity().z()
```

I would like to use both `.velocity()` (as a subvector) and  `.velocity().z()` (as a single number) at the same time.

I also would like to avoid defining any extra variable. I prefer everything be interpreted at the compile time (due to performance priority).

Is this implementation possible in c++?

In an attempt, I have considered returning another class with a functor. But beside the problem of compile time interpretation there is an issue with `const` as `.velocity()` does not know whether it will be followed by a `const` or non-`const` form of `.z()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

class Particle
{
public:
    arma::vec::fixed<9> data;

    inline double velocity_z() const
    {
        return data(5);
    }
    inline double& velocity_z()
    {
        return data(5);
    }

    inline const arma::subview_col<double> position() const
    {
        return data.subvec(0,2);
    }
    inline arma::subview_col<double> position()
    {
        return data.subvec(0,2);
    }
    inline const arma::subview_col<double> velocity() const
    {
        return data.subvec(3,5);
    }
    inline arma::subview_col<double> velocity()
    {
        return data.subvec(3,5);
    }
    inline const arma::subview_col<double> acceleration() const
    {
        return data.subvec(6,8);
    }
    inline arma::subview_col<double> acceleration()
    {
        return data.subvec(6,8);
    }
};

arma::vec vector3(double x,double y,double z)
{
    return {x,y,z};
}

int main()
{
    Particle p;
    p.position()=vector3(1.1,2.1,3.1);
    p.velocity()=vector3(1.2,2.2,3.2);
    p.velocity_z()=10.0;
    p.acceleration()=vector3(1.3,2.3,3.3);
    p.data.print();
    return 0;
}


// output:

//     1.1000
//     2.1000
//     3.1000
//     1.2000
//     2.2000
//    10.0000
//     1.3000
//     2.3000
//     3.3000
```

make:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test1.cpp -larmadillo
```

[Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to keep physically dissimilar quantities in a common vector. Why not have three separate vectors for position, velocity and acceleration?

Comment: My advice create your own `arma::subview_col<double>` type by inheriting then add new `::x()`, `::y()`, `::z()` methods to it.

Comment: @FredrickGauss, could you please give more elaborate about this idea?

Comment: Never mind, @StoryTeller already implemented it in a smart way. But I was thinking instead of accessing `ref.data(3);` in `::x()`, reducing `::fixed<9> data` to `::fixed<3> data` so it would be simple `return ref.data(0);` for `::x()`.

Comment: @FredrickGauss It does not work as `arma::vec` and `arma::subview_col` are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one possible solution would be to return a proxy object that both exposes the `.{x|y|z}()` member functions and is implicitly convertible to your vector type.

Conceptually like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

using vector_t = /* your library type */;

template<bool RValue>
class vector_proxy {
  using return_type = typename std::conditional<RValue, vector_t&&, vector_t const&>::type;
  vector_t &ref;
public:
  vector_proxy(vector_t &ref) : ref(ref) {}
  vector_proxy(vector_proxy const&) = delete;
  vector_proxy& operator=(vector_proxy const&) = delete;
  vector_proxy(vector_proxy&&) = delete;
  vector_proxy& operator=(vector_proxy&&) = delete;

  auto x() { /* code to produce x */ }
  auto y() { /* code to produce y */ }
  auto z() { /* code to produce z */ }

  operator return_type() { return static_cast<return_type>(ref); } 
};
```

Why a template? Because I would imagine you'd want different behavior, depending on the value category of the particle object.

We wouldn't want to return a non-const reference to a particles internal data if that particle is an lvalue. If it's an rvalue, we may as well return an rvalue reference as well so the code behaves "as expected".

The member function `velocity()` of the particle can have a value category qualifier to differentiate the two cases. And the template above just captures common behavior and abstracts the differences.

```
class particle {
  // Members
public:
  vector_proxy<false> velocity() const& { return {/* A ref to the velocity member */}; }
  vector_proxy<true> velocity() && { return {/* A ref to the velocity member */}; }

  // More functionality
};
```

---

Since you clarified in the comments that `velocity` always shuold returns a new vector object by value (an excellent default approach, btw), while allowing to modify the particle as well. The solution above needs to be updated:

```
class particle;

template<bool ByRef>
class vector_proxy {
  using return_type =
    typename std::conditional<ByRef, double&, double>::type;

  using ref_type =
    typename std::conditional<ByRef, particle&, particle const&>::type;

  ref_type ref;
public:
  vector_proxy(ref_type ref) : ref(ref) {}
  vector_proxy(vector_proxy const&) = delete;
  vector_proxy& operator=(vector_proxy const&) = delete;
  vector_proxy(vector_proxy&&) = delete;
  vector_proxy& operator=(vector_proxy&&) = delete;

  return_type x();
  return_type y();
  return_type z();

  operator vector_t(); 
};

class particle {
  // Members

  template<bool>
  friend class vector_proxy;
public:
  vector_proxy<false> velocity() const { return {*this}; }
  vector_proxy<true>  velocity()       { return {*this}; }

  // More functionality
};

template<bool ByRef>
auto vector_proxy<ByRef>::x -> return_type {
  return ref.data(3);
}

template<bool ByRef>
auto vector_proxy<ByRef>::y -> return_type {
  return ref.data(4);
}

template<bool ByRef>
auto vector_proxy<ByRef>::z -> return_type {
  return ref.data(5);
}

template<bool ByRef>
vector_proxy<ByRef>::operator vector_t() {
  return ref.data.subvec(3, 5)
}
```

And that should be it.

Comment: Thank you very much. At this line: `inline const vector_proxy<false> velocity() const& { return vector_proxy<false>(data.subvec(3,5)); }` I receive an error: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘vector_t& {aka arma::subview_col<double>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘const arma::subview_col<double>’`. Have I made any mistake?

Comment: @ar2015 - You didn't. My solution didn't account for the use of `subvec(3,5)`, I thought you use an instance variable. It's an error indicative of trying to bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary. But if you have a temporary, you don't need this elaborate scheme. The `vector_proxy` can own the temporary. Give me a moment to update the solution.

Comment: @ar2015 - There you have it.

Comment: Trying the [update](https://pastebin.com/Ak9UwXuJ), I found new [errors](https://pastebin.com/XPCY4NK4). Is there anything wrong with `move constructor`?

Comment: @ar2015 - You mixed and matched my original code with the updated solution in the edit. Note there is no `&` and `&&` qualifiers in the new version. Nor are any functions deleted anymore.

Comment: @ar2015 - And you don't need to add `operator=` for `vector_proxy`. The implicitly generated ones are perfectly okay now.

Comment: [updated code](https://pastebin.com/1WW2FppJ) gives me this error: `test2.cpp:96:21: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     p.velocity().z()=10.0;` doesn't my operator suffice?

Comment: @ar2015 - Okay. So let me understand. You want velocity to both return a new object **and** allow modifying the particle internal state?

Comment: @ar2015 - Okay. Another update. Hopefully this addresses all your needs.

Comment: I like the idea. But it discards qualifiers ([error](https://pastebin.com/QSt1jRVt)), ([source](https://pastebin.com/JWVtkMYp)).

Comment: @ar2015 - You know, if you want a complete production quality worth solution, with all the details ironed out, that's paid labor. I posted a final swing at it. If you get more errors I'm afraid you'll have to work through them.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. By `std::add_reference` do you mean `add_lvalue_reference` or `add_rvalue_reference`? `add_reference` is not a member of `std`.

Comment: @ar2015 - I already fixed that. And after fixing that a better alternative came to mind. So I edited that, again, because my pride wouldn't let me do otherwise.

Comment: You are a generous programmer.

Comment: The [code](https://pastebin.com/39kEJ2re) is now compilable. I have added a `operator=(arma::vec const&)` and it lead to `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: @ar2015 - `*this=a` in `operator=` is a recursive call. Seems like you wanted something else there.

Comment: Yes, without these operators I get errow: `error: use of deleted function ‘vector_proxy<ByRef>& vector_proxy<ByRef>::operator=(vector_proxy<ByRef>&&) [with bool ByRef = true]’` at `p.velocity()=vector3(1.2,2.2,3.2);`. It happens when you assign a complete vector to a subvector. I would like to redirect the assignment of subvector.

Comment: @ar2015 - I didn't say remove your `operator=`, just fix it to not call **itself** recursively.

Comment: `ref=a;` is also wrong. It gives error. Let me think.

Comment: @ar2015 - `ref.data = a;` by any chance?

Comment: `ref.data.subvec(3, 5)=a;`

Comment: The final code is [here](https://pastebin.com/QJFQB7GW). You can put paste it in your answer for the future reference. I appreciate the time and efforts you have dedicated.